# Error while indexing csv file

Tags: exception, csv, indexing, forge, endeca

I am trying to index csv file in Endeca.Indexing is working fine in the case the line length is less than 65536.For large data it is throwing below exception.

FATAL 02/18/14 15:45:53.122 UTC (1392738353122) FORGE {baseline}: TextObjectInputStream: while reading "/opt/soft/endeca/apps/MyApp/data/processing/TestRecord.csv", delimiter " " not found within allowed distance of 65536 characters. ............................................. .............................................. ERROR 02/17/14 16:10:58.060 UTC (1392653458060) FORGE {baseline}: I/O Exception: Error reading data from Java: EdfException thrown in: edf/src/format/Shared/TextObjectInputStream.cpp:76. Message is: exit called

How can I increase this limit to index large data(having more than 65537 character in single line) in Endeca ?.

Comment: I believe it is 65537 for a reason (2^16 + 1). Are you sure your line contains that much data?

Comment: @radimpe yes I am sure line contains that much data.It is an html content.

Answer (score 1):

I imagine you've fixed this.  If not, your error is when the row delimiter isn't set correctly  in your Record Adapter.

If your records are legitimately that long in a CSV file, switch to XML or something else.

Comment: Thanks a lot for reply.As an work around we are indexing less data in Endeca.But I will try the xml option.